# Use "\\;+;" as a regular expression not working

Tags: r

I am trying to extract `+` or `-` sign from a column of a dataframe to a vector:

If I have this dataframe:

```
sample    info   
 A        man;+;yes;no
 B        man;-;no;no
 C        woman;+;yes;no
 D        man;NA;no;no
 E        woman;-;yes;no
```

I am trying to extract the sign (+ or -) contained in `info` column to a vector:

```
strand<-vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(grepl(";\\+;", df[i,2]) == TRUE){
  strand[i]<-'+'
  }
  if(grepl(";-;", df[i,2]) == TRUE){
  strand[i]<-'-'
  }
  else{strand[i]<-NA}
}
```

But I am not getting the `+` sign:

```
print(strand)
NA - NA  NA  -
```

Why my loop is printing NA instead of `+` sign?
Thanks!

Comment: Escape the metachar: `";\\+;"`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas I've edited the question to a more concrete problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized solution, no need for `for` loops.

First create a result vector of the appropriate length. Then use index vectors to fill it with the new values. Note that when there are `NA`'s, logical indices do not work, use `which`.

```
strand <- character(nrow(df))

i <- grepl(";\\+;", df[[2]])
strand[which(i)] <- "+"

j <- grepl(";-;", df[[2]])
strand[which(j)] <- "-"

is.na(strand) <- !(i | j)

strand
#[1] "+" "-" "+" NA  "-"
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
sample    info   
A        man;+;yes;no
B        man;-;no;no
C        woman;+;yes;no
D        man;NA;no;no
E        woman;-;yes;no
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape character \ so your code will look like

```
grep(";\\+;", df$info)
```